# Erro ao gerar PDF, Undefined variable: o (View:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
  metodo gera pdf: 
  ordemController

 $ordens = Ordem::all();
 return \PDF::loadView('ordem.detalhes', compact('ordens'))
->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')
 ->stream('export.pdf');


  view
  <h1 class="text-warning">Ordem numero: {{$o->cliente_id}}</h1>

 <ul>
 <li>
    <b>Cliente:</b>  {{ $o->cliente->nome}}
</li>

<li>
    <b>Telefone:</b>  {{ $o->cliente->telefone}}
</li>

<li>
    <b>Data:</b> {{ $o->data }}
</li>

<li>
    <b>Problema:</b> {{ $o->problema }}
</li>

<li>
    <b>Valor :</b> R$ {{ $o->valor }}
</li>

<li>
    <b>Produto incluso :</b>  {{ $o->produto->nome}}
</li>

<li>
    <b>Tipo de servico :</b>  {{ $o->servico->nome}}
</li>
```

---

view de listagem:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered
  table-hover"> 
   <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>   
    <th> Descrição</th>
    <th class="text-right"> Valor entrada </th>
    <th class="text-right"> Valor saída</th>
    <th class="text-right"> Qtd. estoque </th>
    <th class="text-center">Opções</th>

     </tr>

@foreach($produtos as $p)
<tr class="{{$p->qtd_estoque <=2?'danger':''}}">
    <td>{{$p->nome}}</td>   
    <td>{{$p->descricao}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{$p->valor_entrada}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{$p->valor_saida}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{$p->qtd_estoque}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">

        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <a href="/ordem/detalhes/ <?=$o->id ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
        </a>
```

Comment: Antes de mais nada, poderia definir melhor seu problema? Em segundo poderia postar sua view completa?

Comment: O metodo funciona somente na view de lista

Comment: Você usa o site errado leia: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Note que o aviso informa que a variável **"$o"** é indefinida. Ou seja, ela não existe.

Este aviso é exibido toda vez que você tenta utilizar uma variável que não existe.

E no seu código, observe que no seguinte trecho, você define que a variável a ser passada para a view é a **"ordens"**.

No seguinte trecho:

```
 loadView('ordem.detalhes', compact('ordens'))
```

E na view você chama a variável **"$o"** que não existe.

Troque a variável **"$o"** chamada na view pela variável **$ordens** que foi passada para view.

E para verificar a existência de uma variável antes de utilizá-la, utiliza-se a função `isset()` .

Exemplo:

```
if( isset($variavel) ){
   // faz alguma coisa
}
```

Referência da função `isset()`

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php